# Differential equation of space curve with given curvature and torsion

Tags: differential-geometry

What is the differential equation of a 3D space curve whose varying curvature and torsion are given as functions of arc length? (up to rotation and translation of Euclidean motions?)

EDIT1:

Motivation in asking the question is also about uniqueness of associated curve embeddings like e.g., on the following  two $ R^2$ surfaces containing lines with *zero curvature and non-zero torsion*... which I hoped would be associated with some constant of integration.

1) Straight line rulings of a One sheet hyperboloid ruled surface, skewed to the central axis.

2) Central axis $ u = 0 $ of helicoid

$$ ( u \cos t, u \sin t , c t) $$

I am teased by the *generalized Frenet-Serret* formulation that includes *geodesic torsion, geodesic curvature and normal curvature*.

One reference to generalized Frenet-Serret is among last pages of DJStruik's Differential Geometry Lectures Book 2nd Edition.

Even at  risk of attracting some adverse  reaction for vagueness, I ask : Why is there no concept of a scalar torsion component of *normal torsion*? This remark may however be ignored for this discussion.

Comment: See the Frenet-Serret formulas: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas

Answer (score 1):

All spaces curves parametrized by arc length satisfy a system of structural differential equations, called [Frenet-Serret formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas).

These equations show that the curvature and torsion determine the curve up to a rigid motion.

Comment: Not quite: you can get nonuniqueness at points where the curvature and torsion are $0$.

Comment: For example, with $\kappa = 3 s^2$ and $\tau = 0$, you could have $T = [\cos(s^3), \sin(s^3), 0]$ or $T = [\cos(s^3), \text{sgn}(s) \sin(s^3), 0]$, producing non-congruent curves.