# Parametrising a curve using curvature and torsion functions

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I am trying to get a parametrization of the curve whose curvature and torsion functions are given as

$$\kappa(s)= \dfrac{1}{1+s^2} ,\;\; \tau(s) = \dfrac{s}{1+s^2}$$

I know that in general it is not possible to get parametrizations from the curvature and torsion functions, but I was hoping this one would fit the bill.

The curvature function is that of a catenary curve, so I thought a parametrization would be along the lines of

$$ x(s) = \int \cos(\arctan(s))\mathsf{ds}, \;\; y(s) =\int \sin(\arctan(s))\mathsf{ds}, \;\; z(s) = ?$$ Am I on the right track??

Further the curvature and torsion functions indicate that this a geodesic on a cone. But I am not able to push on from here.

Answer (score 1):

Cone geodesic should be

$$
\left(
   \begin{array}{c}
     x \\
     y \\
     z
   \end{array}
 \right) = \sqrt{a^{2}+s^{2}}
 \left(
   \begin{array}{c}
     \sin \beta \cos \left( \csc \beta \tan^{-1} \frac{s}{a} \right) \\
     \sin \beta \sin \left( \csc \beta \tan^{-1} \frac{s}{a} \right) \\
     \cos \beta
   \end{array}
 \right)$$

but with
\begin{align*}
  \kappa &= \frac{a^{2}\cot \beta}{(a^{2}+s^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}} \\
  \tau &= \frac{as\cot \beta}{(a^{2}+s^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\end{align*}

instead.

Comment: Well, I thought any geodesic on a cone should satisfy the relation that $\dfrac{d}{ds}(\dfrac{\tau}{\kappa})$ is a constant. Am I right?

Comment: Your curve also does that. But I wished to know if the curve i mentioned is also a geodesic on a cone possibly.

Comment: Unlikely.  The intrinsic equations seem to be invariant under the scaling of $a$ for fixed $\beta$.  May your case is for other kind of surface.

Comment: Ok and what about the parametrisation of the curve?Can that be found?

Comment: Maybe easier than the following : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1603719/what-is-the-space-curve-with-curvature-and-torsion-obeying

Comment: This may help http://www.emis.de/journals/BMAA/repository/docs/BMAA3-2-19.pdf

Comment: Thanks to both you guys for those links