# Parametric form of conical helix

Tags: parametric

Given a cone as

\begin{array}{l}
x=s\cos t\\
y=s\sin t\\
z=s\cot\alpha\end{array}

How could I get parametric form of **any** conical helix?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Parametrized by arc-length**

\begin{align*}
  \mathbf{r}(s) &=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \dfrac{as}{\sqrt{1+b^2}} \, \cos (b \ln s) \\[2pt]
    \dfrac{as}{\sqrt{1+b^2}} \, \sin (b \ln s) \\[2pt]
    s\sqrt{1-a^2}
  \end{pmatrix} \\[5pt]
  \kappa &= \frac{ab}{s} \\[5pt]
  \tau &= \frac{b\sqrt{1-a^2}}{s} \\[5pt]
  \frac{\tau}{\kappa} &= \frac{\sqrt{1-a^2}}{a} \\[5pt]
  \left( \frac{\tau}{\kappa} \right)' &= 0
\end{align*}

where $\cot \alpha=\dfrac{\sqrt{(1-a^2)(1+b^2)}}{a}$ for $a\in (0,1)$ and $b\in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{ 0 \}$.

See also the **cone geodesic** in [**another answer**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1650188/parametrising-a-curve-using-curvature-and-torsion-functions/1650433#1650433) for which $\dfrac{\tau}{\kappa}=\dfrac{s}{a}$ and so it's a **conical spiral** instead of helix.