# The parametric equation of a cone $z = \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}$.

Tags: calculus, parametric

The given equation is -
$z = \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}} , 0 \le z \le 1$

> Let $x = r \cos t$, $y = r \sin t$ and $z = r$; where $0 \le r \le 1$
>   and $0 \le t \le 2 \pi$.

Since $z$ is taken from $0$ to $1$ , so $r$ is also taken from $0$ to $1$

**I didn't understand why $t$ is in between $0$ and $2 \pi$?**

Comment: If you wrap a piece of paper (with negligible thickness) into a cone, you can make it more than one turns, then $t$ could be beyond $[0,2\pi)$.  You could illustrate the concept of isometric deformation with different domains in angle.  See also parametrization of cone with geodesics in my post [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1650188/parametrising-a-curve-using-curvature-and-torsion-functions/1650433#1650433).

Answer (score 1):

At any given value of $r$ you get a value of $z,$ the height of the cone.

But a height and a value $r$ by themselves don't give you a cone. To have a cone you need a circular base. It will also have a circular cross section in any plane parallel to the base between the base and the apex.

Now review parametric formulas for a circle and see anything matches part of what you see here.

Comment: In the parametric formula of circle in $x-y$ plane, $x = r cos t$ and $y = r sin t$ . Where $t$ is the angle between $x$ axis and the position vector of point $(x,y)$. To make a complete circle, $t$ moves from 0 to $2\pi$. So, in the formula of base of cone, which is a circle, $t$ should also move from 0 to $2\pi$ to make the comlete base. Is this okay?

Comment: That is the right idea.